# Form submit goes back to login screen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET MVC 1 web application using the ASP.NET Membership provider. On my local box, when I submit data to a form, the redirect takes it to the proper location (with Controller.RedirectToRoute). On the server where it is supposed to live, form submitting takes me back to the login page. The data posts properly, but I'm just redirected incorrectly.

I recall dealing with this a few years ago (in a non-MVC application) and it was due to a problem with the Web.Config relative to the Membership provider.

I can't imagine I'm the only one that's had this problem. What should I be looking for in my web.config that could be related to this?

Thanks ahead of time.

---

**EDIT**

Here is my authentication and membership portion of the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="IPS" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="IPS" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="IPS" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add applicationName="IPS" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: I've discovered a deeper issue than what I've mentioned here. This question is now obsolete. Here is my new question based on the discovery I made in the event log: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810982/mvc-1-and-iis-7-error-code-4011

Answer (score 0):

MVC 1 uses Forms auth by default.  You may want to check your forms auth settings to make sure that you aren't being redirected as part of security.

Comment: I've posted my web.config pieces to see if that has anything eye-popping?

Answer (score -1):

If you using the MySQL like a user data storage, such problem can happened because of different MySQL Connector version on our local pc and server

Comment: That is not the case. I'm using MS SQL Server locally hosted.

Comment: why -1? i had such problem in my project. when i test the project localy - every thing works fine, but when publish to server - the authendification not working. the solution was to change the MySQL connector to another version.

Comment: Sorry, found the mistake. I thought that you using MySQL